# Flutter - pass text listened to rich text

Tags: flutter, text, text-to-speech, edit, speech-to-text

I made this application in flutter that when I say something it translates it to text, estoy usando el plugin tts, but you know how I can pass the text to an input, that is, to convert the text to an editable text in an input (TextFormField), here I leave my code, I hope your help from the heart.

I have searched for more information in forums and so far nothing.

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tts/flutter_tts.dart';

class TextVoicePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: _appBar(context),
        body: Stack(children: <Widget>[TextVoice()]),
      ),
    );
  }

  _appBar(BuildContext context) {
    return PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  end: Alignment.centerRight,
                  colors: [Colors.pink[900], Colors.red[800]])),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_left),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  }),
              Text('Texto a Voz',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  )),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.help_outline),
                onPressed: () {},
                color: Colors.white,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class TextVoice extends StatelessWidget {
  final FlutterTts flutterTts = FlutterTts();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();

    Future _speak(String text) async {
      await flutterTts.setLanguage("es-MX");
      await flutterTts.setPitch(1);
      await flutterTts.speak(text);
    }

    Future _stop() async {
      await flutterTts.stop();
    }

    _fondoApp() {
      final gradiente = Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
                end: FractionalOffset(0.0, 1.0),
                colors: [Colors.black87, Colors.black])),
      );

      return Stack(
        children: <Widget>[gradiente],
      );
    }

    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        _fondoApp(),
        (SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Introduce el texto.',
                    labelStyle:
                        TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 16.0),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.pink[900]),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.pink[50]),
                    ),
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white30, fontSize: 16.0),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                  controller: textEditingController,
                  cursorColor: Colors.white,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 16.0),
                  maxLines: 13,
                ),
              ),
              OutlineButton.icon(
                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                label: Text('Escuchar'),
                textColor: Colors.green,
                icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                onPressed: () => _speak(textEditingController.text),
              ),
              OutlineButton.icon(
                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                textColor: Colors.red,
                label: Text('Detener'),
                icon: Icon(Icons.stop),
                onPressed: () => _stop(),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

It is just passing the results to an editable text in an input.

Comment: Sorry but your question is a bit unclear what error are you exactly getting?

Comment: I have used your code, and what I understand so far is that, when I type something in the textfield and then press the green button, then my phone speaks exactly what is written in the textfield. 
So my question is that what you exactly want ?

Comment: I need the text to go from place to scaffold or container, pass to an entrance, and have it become modifiable text, just that.

Comment: That is, instead of 'just text', go to a modifiable text in an input, or in this case a TextFormField

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this: https://pub.dev/packages/quill_delta.  Quill is a multiplatform Rich Text Editor and is ported to Flutter.  Or maybe https://pub.dev/packages/zefyr, also claiming to be a rich text editor.

Comment: I mean that the text becomes normal editable text, I don't look for styles or something like that, that is, I say something through the microphone and it is transcribed to a textfield in flutter

Comment: So you don't want "rich text".  You want plain String values.  I think the speech-to-text stuff will do that easily.